# how to call a partial view inside a view in mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

i have created a partial view inside a shared folder, I wanted to use this view on every page 
My View is

```
    @model IEnumerable<Drgangil.tbl_testimonial>
@*<header class="home-title test-title">
    <h3>Testimonials</h3>
</header>*@

<div class="flexslider-testimonials">
    <ul class="slides">
        @foreach(var item in Model)
        { 
        <li>
            <div class="home-test">
                <p>@item.testimonial_desc</p>
            </div><!--end home-test-->
            <div class="test-author">
                <img class="item-avatar" src="~/images/home/testimonial.jpg" alt="" />
                <p class="test-author-name">@item.patient_name</p>
                <p>Assistant Manager</p>
            </div><!--end test-author-->
        </li>
        }
    </ul>
</div><!--end flexslider-->
```

and i am calling this partial view 
in the index page

```
    @Html.Partial("_Testimonial")
```

but its is showing an error 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
and error in foreach line

```
     <div class="flexslider-testimonials">
     <ul class="slides">
          @foreach(var item in Model)
         { 
         <li>
```

please help me with this. i am not getting where i am going wrong

Comment: Your partial expects a model that is `IEnumerable<Drgangil.tbl_testimonial>` but you not passing a model to the partial, hence its `null` which result in the exception.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke Thanks for the ans , Can you please give me brief explanation.

Comment: You would need to use `@Html.Partial("_Testimonial", Model.someProperty)` where the model in the `Index.cshtml` view contains a property that is `IEnumerable<Drgangil.tbl_testimonial>` (and not `null`). But you have said you want this in every view, which means it should be in the layout, and you should be using `@Html.Action()` to call a ChildOnly method that returns a partial (it would make no sense to use `@Html.Partial()` because every view would need a model containing a property that is `IEnumerable<Drgangil.tbl_testimonial>`)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke. hi thanks i have done the changes now i am calling this partial view in layout page but again also it showing same error

Comment: Are you using `@Html.Action()` - its not gong to work using `@Html.Partial()` unless you pass a model to the partial but that would not make sense. (and the code in the controller method needs to initialize a model that is `IEnumerable<Drgangil.tbl_testimonial>` and then return a partial view based on that model

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, Thanks